# How to use the raster calculator in the processing modeler of QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-processing

I am trying to create a easy way to do raster analysis by building a model for two way raster calculations. I have two raster layers that I want to combine into a single raster. For now I've done this manually by doing the raster calculation myself but for the future I want to be able to input these layers into a model without having to go through the trouble.

What is the proper annotation of this formula?

How I've tried it is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the SAGA provider raster calculator, you need to use the [SAGA syntax](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.2.0/grid_calculus_1.html), which is:
(g1+g2)/2

Comment: It appears the SAGA syntax link provided above no longer works. This link has a bit more info: http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.1.4/grid_calculus_1.html

Answer (score 0):

Try `(A+B)/2`, or refresh your Processing plugin.